# Is convolutions just conditional probability?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, convolution

I have never used convolutions before, but I decided to take a look at them today. They seem just an application of conditional probability. Is there anything special about them beyond applying conditional probability and LOTP?

Are there problems (in the context of probability) that can be solved with convolutions but not with conditional probability?

Comment: Convolution of 2 fonctions is an operation which is central in mathematical analysis, especialy in harmonic analysis (Fourier transform, etc...). It is by no means restricted to probability.

Comment: @JeanMarie Right. I edited my question to be specific that I am asking about convolutions in the context of probability only.

Comment: What do you mean, convolutions are just conditional probability? A conditional expectation is a random variable $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}](\omega)$, where $X$ is a random variable and $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra; a convolution is binary operation an an appropriate function space. The most common use of convolution in probability is to obtain the distribution of the sum of independent random variables, which is not directly related to conditioning.